# How to fix this error I’m getting from Amazon s3: ETagMissing: No access to ETag property on response. Check CORS configuration to expose ETag header

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am running into a error "ETagMissing: No access to ETag property on response. Check CORS configuration to expose ETag header." when running a multipart upload to AWS. I searched the whole net and cant find a way to add this Etag to my bucket CORS policy. I don't know the properties of it and theres no documnetation.

My current CORS policy:

```
[
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST",
        "DELETE",
        "HEAD"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": []
}
```

]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply add `ETag` in the `ExposeHeaders` array on your CORS configuration.

- Click on your bucket
- Click on  **Authorization** tab, move down to **CORS**

Your CORS config should looks like :

```
{
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT",
        "POST"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "your_origin_url"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "ETag" // The line to add
    ]
}
```

Comment: You are a godsend! I have been stuck on this for so long. All the reference articles never mention this.

Comment: Same here @Apezzz ! Thanks Nehemie KOFFI and thanks Marcus for asking the question! I didn't even know we could set up these policies on the bucket..

Answer (score 1):

> Check CORS configuration to expose ETag header.

The error message is telling you exactly what to do. Your CORS policy needs to add `ETag` in the `ExposeHeaders` array.

You currently have an empty `ExposeHeaders` array so all headers are being blocked by CORS.

Comment: More precisely, [some response headers](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-safelisted-response-header-name) are accessible by default to scripts, but `ETag` indeed is not one of them and needs to be explicitly exposed by the server.